# SimpleBlobDetector - Isolate blobs that are distinct from surrounding

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm using `SimpleBlobDetector` to locate the decimal dots and other types of punctuation marks, as can be seen in the image below, sometimes the detector picks up blobs out of the solid areas of the text (The bottom of the middle 9), I'm looking for a way to filter out those detections either through the `SimpleBlobDetector` or in post process.

Is there a way to specify that a blob must be separated from it's background color? Maybe an edge detection method?

Your help is appreciated.

Detector code is:

```py
    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    params.filterByArea = True
    params.minArea = 30
    params.minThreshold = 50
    params.maxThreshold = 200
    params.filterByConvexity = True
    params.minConvexity = 0.87
    params.filterByColor = True
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
    detections = detector.detect(img)
```

Output image with detections

[image: Output image with detections]
Original:

[image: Original image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `SimpleBlobDetector`, here's a solution utilizing edge/contour detection which allows for more filtering control. The main idea is

- Convert image to grayscale
- Gaussian blur
- Threshold image to separate main features from background
- Perform canny edge detection
- Dilate canny image to enhance and close contours
- Find contours in image and filter using a min/max threshold area

Threshold image

[image]

Canny edge detection

[image]

Dilate to enhance contours

[image]

Detected and filtered contours based on area

[image]

Output results

> contours detected: 1

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

original_image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
image = original_image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 110, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
canny = cv2.Canny(thresh, 150, 255, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imshow("dilate", dilate)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("canny", canny)

# Find contours in the image
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

contours = []

threshold_min_area = 1100
threshold_max_area = 1200

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > threshold_min_area and area < threshold_max_area:
        cv2.drawContours(original_image,[c], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
        contours.append(c)

cv2.imshow("detected", original_image) 
print('contours detected: {}'.format(len(contours)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```